# How to use ffprobe to obtain certain information about mp4/h.264 files

Tags: ffmpeg

I am but a lowly PHP developer that has been tasked with retrieving some basic information about 100's of thousands of video files.  I've had some luck using `ffmpeg` and extracting the `video bitrate`, `video width`, `video height`, `duration`, and `aspect ratio` from them, but with an error ratio of about 5%, this still leaves me with an enormous number of files that I don't know how to deal with. The videos DO play,
but the massive amount of data that `ffmpeg` returns in has me baffled as to how parse the returned *XML* to find what I need with all the conditions that I seem to be encountering.  (The files are a collection from the past 15 years or so, some newly encoded, others converted years ago)

At any rate, I found the following use of `ffprobe` to get duration, and was hoping that someone here who understands the complexities of using `ffmpeg` & `ffprobe` would be kind enough to assist me with finding the other values I need in a more straightforward way than the crazy code I'm using myself, created to climb through the full results of `ffmpeg`.

```sh
ffprobe -i "video.mp4" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

Thanks so very much in advance.

**CLARIFICATION:**

I should add that with the below cmd, I can *"see"* what I need, but I don't understand how to extract what I need. E.g. retrieving the VIDEO bitrate, and suppressing/ignoring the AUDIO bitrate, or determining which of 2 different durations to use (Audio/Video durations?)

```sh
C:\>ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height,bit_rate,duration \
-of default=noprint_wrappers=1 input.mp4
```

```sh
duration=1712.000000
bit_rate=64000
width=320
height=240
duration=1711.946113
bit_rate=359827
duration=1712.000000
bit_rate=N/A
duration=1712.000000
bit_rate=N/A
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you only want the information from the first video stream use `-select_streams v:0`:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=width,height,duration,bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 input.mp4
```

Example output:

```
width=640
height=480
duration=10.000000
bit_rate=942704
```

- To see a list all entries use `-show_streams` and/or `-show_format` instead of `-show_entries`.
- See [FFprobe Documentation: Writers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers) for various output formatting styles.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks so much for the assist....I had to accept the other answer only because I was alerted of it first, and it did the trick..

Comment: @GDP Please consider: notified first in this case, because it's the latest answer.

Comment: @poor I take the rep point quite seriously, but this answer wasn't on my screen to accept until I accept the other, then it appeared, thus the immediate apology.  Sorry everyone...really didn't mean to offend.

Answer (score 11):

[Source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)

If you want to get the `bit_rate` of the first video stream you could use:

```sh
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate \
-of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

Where `-select_steams v:0` is selecting the first video stream and `:nokey=1` gives the value without the key. You could also extract the information by piping it to grep but I'm not sure if that's available on your system.

```sh
ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=width,height,bit_rate,duration \
-of default=noprint_wrappers=1 input.mp4 | grep -oP "(?<=bit_rate\=)[0-9]+"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: "piping it to grep"...sounds like something I might have done as a teenager, lol...THANKS for the assist!

Comment: Thanks @GDP but LordNeckbeard's is the answer you should probably accept as it was published first